# Is it possible to split a server config into small ones in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Having a virtualserver with lots of `location` directives in Nginx, is it possible to separate them into several files?

Example:

onefile.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location 1 { ... }
    location 2 { ... }
    location 3 { ... }
}
```

Change to:

server.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    include server.location1.conf
    include server.location2.conf
    include server.location3.conf
}
```

server.location1.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location 1 { ... }
}
```

server.location2.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location 2 { ... }
}
```

server.location3.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location 3 { ... }
}
```

Comment: So you're asking about multiple .conf files that apply to the same domain?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the include directive maybe that is what I need. It's because my Drupal installation needs many `location` directives, and I don't want to mess up the main config, so after I finish testing Drupal, I just delete that config file and that's it

Comment: Yes, it is possible. just do not include the whole server config in each file, just the locations. 
is that the actual question?